# Is the resulting bytecode generated in Python deterministic?

Tags: python

Given a Python interpreter (CPython, Jython, etc), is the bytecode generated deterministic?
That is, if I compile 2 different scripts that differ only in whitespace, but otherwise syntactically equivalent, would the chosen compiler generate exactly the same bytecodes?

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing you could try for a few programs to convince yourself that it either is or it isn't deterministic.

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario where it wouldn't. However, there are no formal guarantees. Why do you ask?

Comment: I think the pyc files contain source code line numbers, so the answer is, probably, no.

Comment: "scripts that only differ in whitespace" - I can give you python programs that only differ in whitespace but still do different things. Whitespace (as in indentation) actually matters in python. In cases where different whitespace doesn't result in a _semantic_ difference, the resulting operations wouldn't be different either.

Comment: If you add or remove newlines, the bytecode will be different, as line offsets are included to facilitate debugging and traceback generation.

Comment: your title and your question are not relative. whether it's a deterministic process has nothing to do with whether it generates the same bytecode. The compile process is always deterministic (because it's a compiler on a computer based on non-randomised sourcecode). Please change your title.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but these line nunmbers are not a direct part of the bytecodes, just an annotation to it; while the compiled result might differ in these line numbers if a newline is added in the script, the actual opcodes wouldn't...

Comment: @l4mpi: It is *not clear* what the OP is talking about. Sure, *just* the bytecode is the same, but the offsets are stored on disk with the bytecode.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I'm not sure I understand your point about the title and question. I'm not asking about the compile process but rather the data on the disk.

Comment: @l4mpi, I understand what you mean about the whitespace. I'm interested in programs that do the exact same thing but are not textually equivalent in some trivial manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not clear what you are looking for, *exactly*. Syntactically the same code is going to result in the same instructions being executed, certainly. But even syntactically equivalent python files can generate different `.pyc` cached bytecode files. Adding or removing newlines will result in different line offsets:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     # in the interpreter, comments will do the same job as newlines
...     baz
...     # extra newlines or comments push the bytecode offsets
...     return 42
... 
>>> def bar():
...     baz
...     return 42
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (baz)
              3 POP_TOP             

  5           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (42)
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (baz)
              3 POP_TOP             

  3           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (42)
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the different values in the left-hand column; the interpreter will still behave exactly the same, but the offsets differ.

The bytecode and offsets can be accessed separately leaving what the interpreter executes equal:

```
>>> foo.__code__.co_lnotab
'\x00\x02\x04\x02'
>>> bar.__code__.co_lnotab
'\x00\x01\x04\x01'
>>> foo.__code__.co_code == bar.__code__.co_code
True
```

Comment: More precisely, what you're referring to is an [`Instruction`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/dis.html#dis.Instruction), which _contains_ an opcode representing the operation - while the `Instruction` may differ, the `opcode` won't.

Comment: @l4mpi: sure, but I strongly suspect that the OP is talking about the data *on disk*. In the `.pyc` file and nested code objects still include the offsets.

Comment: if he does a `diff` of the two bytecodes they will be different (even if it is just the offset annotations)  .... he clearly says this in his answer ... how is this wrong in your opinion?

Comment: @MartijnPieters much appreciated :) upvoted, now to delete the previous comment...

Comment: Oh. You already answered my next question I think. Thanks again. Deleted the previous comment.